# Not able to create view for query that involves row_number() function in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I am not able to create view for queries that involves `row_number()`.

Just for example, I have sample table with one column Id. When I try to create view in the following way it gives an error.

```
create or replace view sample_view
(
    ID
)

AS
select Id from (
    select Id,row_number() over (partition  by id) as rownum
    from sample
    where rownum =1 )
```

> Error message : No authorized routine named "ROW_NUMBER" of type
>   "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440,
>   SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.16.53

Not sure why this error is being thrown while creating view, But when I try to run this query:

```
 select Id from (
    select Id,row_number() over (partition  by id) as rownum
    from sample
    where rownum =1 )
```

It's getting executed successfully.

Comment: Still getting the same error, after moving rownum to outer query.

Answer (score 1):

The `where` goes in the outer query, not the subquery:

```
select Id
from (select Id, row_number() over (partition by id order by <something goes here>) as rownum
      from sample
     ) s
where rownum = 1;
```

I assume you have more complex code, because this query is more easily written as:

```
select distinct Id
from sample;
```

EDIT:

DB2 also supports `fetch first 1 row only`, which might be simpler for this purpose:

```
select Id
from sample
order by <something usually goes here>
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: Yes, I have more complex query.  Still I am getting some error after moving where clause to outer query.. Not sure

Comment: I think you are just missing the `order by` clause which is required for `row_number()` (in most databases at least).